# How can i change my c++ project name and my solution name?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm not sure if this is the problem but.
On the solution explorer i changed the project name and the solution name and after hat when i try to run my application i'm getting an error:

> myapp.exe :
>
> The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b). Click OK to
>   close the application.

Maybe i need to change some directories on the hard disk too if i changed the project and solution names in the solution explorer ?

I have Visual Studio 2012 pro the project is C++ console application. Worked good and nothing changed. Started to make this error after changed name of project and solution.

Comment: Try to clean solution and to rebuild everything.

Comment: Working changed in the solution properties the platform target to be x64 i was sure it was working on win32 yesterday i didn't change anything. Anyway now it's working again. Thanks.

Comment: @BenKochavi Post the solution.